# Multiply every other number with out using an array

Tags: c++, string, for-loop

So my problem is bigger but I just do not know what to do with my code. I can do what I want if I use an array works just fine but we are not using arrays yet so I have no idea how to do it. So I have to take user input as a string validate that the string is 16 characters long, all of them are digits, and most importantly I have to multiply every other or even character by 2. Then if it is a double digit add the two digit (ex. 10 1+0). Oh by the way I do not know why but every time I do i%2 == 0 I get the odd numbers. Is it because i is unsigned?

```
for(unsigned i = 1; i < card.length(); i++){

    if (i % 2 == 1){


    }
    else {


    }
}
return sum;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to it. I first needed to create char variable named num. Convert the char to an int using chnum and then multiply.

```
   for(unsigned i = 0; i < card.length(); i++){

    if (i % 2 == 1){

        num = card.at(i);
        chnum = (num -'0');
        add = chnum * 2;

        if(add >= 10){

            char ho = (add + '0');
            string str(1,ho);

            for (unsigned j = 0; j < str.length();j++){

                char digi = str.at(j);
                int chub = (digi - '0');
                cout << digi;
                //add = (chub) + (chub);
            }


        }
        sum += add;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array of strings where each string contains a number.

Go through them checking for 2 conditions:

1. Double the number if it is even (i.e., `i % 2 == 0`)
2. Add the digits if the number has 2 digits (i.e., string's length is 2)

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator> using namespace std;

int TOTAL_CARDS = 16;

void printCards(string msg, string *array) {
    cout<<msg<<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < TOTAL_CARDS; i++) {
        cout<<"array["<<i<<"]="<<array[i]<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"\n"<<endl; }

int main() {
    string cards[TOTAL_CARDS];

    // hardcoded numbers 0 up to TOTAL_CARDS for demo purposes
    for(int i = 0; i < TOTAL_CARDS; i++) {
        cards[i] = to_string(i);
    }

    printCards("Before:", cards);

    for (unsigned i = 1; i < TOTAL_CARDS; i++){
        // double if even
        if (i % 2 == 0){
            cards[i] = to_string(stoi(cards[i]) * 2);
        } 

        // add digits if double digit number
        if (cards[i].length() == 2) {
            // get each digit
            string currentNum = cards[i];
            int firstDigit = currentNum[0] - '0'; // char - '0' gives int
            int secondDigit = currentNum[1] - '0';
            // do sum and put in array
            int sum = firstDigit + secondDigit;
            cards[i] = to_string(sum);
        }

    }

    printCards("After:", cards); }
```

Output:

```
Before:
array[0]=0
array[1]=1
array[2]=2
array[3]=3
array[4]=4
array[5]=5
array[6]=6
array[7]=7
array[8]=8
array[9]=9
array[10]=10
array[11]=11
array[12]=12
array[13]=13
array[14]=14
array[15]=15


After:
array[0]=0
array[1]=1
array[2]=4
array[3]=3
array[4]=8
array[5]=5
array[6]=3
array[7]=7
array[8]=7
array[9]=9
array[10]=2
array[11]=2
array[12]=6
array[13]=4
array[14]=10
array[15]=6
```

If you wanted to get user input for the numbers:

```
// get user to enter numbers
cout<<"Please enter "<<TOTAL_CARDS<<" numbers: "<<endl;
for(int i = 0; i < TOTAL_CARDS; i++) {
    cin>>cards[i];
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply I am trying not use arrays or I can't use them.Otherwise I like your approach.

Comment: Glad to help, I'm unsure how to solve the problem without an array (let us know if you solve it) but don't forget to accept an answer if it solved your problem and to upvote useful answers (helps others find useful answers)